# How to make this Java code formatter more beautiful

Tags: java

I'm learning programming skill from Robert C.Martin《Clean code》.When I read the content about code format,I confused. So I write below code.Can tell me which is good? Or is there any more good way.Thanks for all.

**version one**

```java
    public void insert(Integer userId, MemberCardRecord oldCard, MemberCardRecord newCard) {
        String operate = "Admin option";
        CardUpgradeRecordBuilder builder = CardUpgradeRecordBuilder.create(db().newRecord(CARD_UPGRADE));

        CardUpgradeRecord record = builder.userId(userId).oldCardId(oldCard.getId()).newCardId(newCard.getId())
                .oldGrade(oldCard.getGrade()).newGrade(newCard.getGrade()).oldCardName(oldCard.getCardName())
                .newCardName(newCard.getCardName()).gradeCondition(newCard.getGradeCondition()).operate(operate)
                .build();
        record.insert();
    }
```

**version two**

```java
public void insert(Integer userId,MemberCardRecord oldCard, MemberCardRecord newCard) {
        String operate = "Admin option";
        CardUpgradeRecordBuilder builder = CardUpgradeRecordBuilder.create(db().newRecord(CARD_UPGRADE));

        CardUpgradeRecord record = builder.userId(userId)
                                         .oldCardId(oldCard.getId())
                                         .newCardId(newCard.getId())
                                         .oldGrade(oldCard.getGrade())
                                         .newGrade(newCard.getGrade())
                                         .oldCardName(oldCard.getCardName())
                                         .newCardName(newCard.getCardName())
                                         .gradeCondition(newCard.getGradeCondition())
                                         .operate(operate)
                                         .build();
        record.insert();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a editor like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which formats code automatically?

Comment: *My opinion:* #1 is difficult to read, go with #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **version 3**  but actually it depends on what format you like format doesn't matter when it is compiled.

```
public void insert(Integer userId,MemberCardRecord oldCard, MemberCardRecord newCard) {
        CardUpgradeRecordBuilder
             .create(db().newRecord(CARD_UPGRADE))
             .userId(userId)
             .oldCardId(oldCard.getId())
             .newCardId(newCard.getId())
             .oldGrade(oldCard.getGrade())
             .newGrade(newCard.getGrade())
             .oldCardName(oldCard.getCardName())
             .newCardName(newCard.getCardName())
             .gradeCondition(newCard.getGradeCondition())
             .operate("Admin option")
             .build()
             .insert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code formatting depends on the IDE which you are using. Different IDEs have different methods to format code. You can also configure settings while formatting code in IDE. Main thing is that the code should be cleaner to be understand by others as well.
So it is up to the viewers which format does he/she likes.